# Querying multiple tables having the same column name

Tags: asp.net, database, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

I have about 20 tables in one database, with the same column names i.e.

TeacherName,Subject,Class,etc...

Now I want to query all the tables at once to **display all the rows having teacher name say : "John Travolta"**.

How can I do that? I saw in some posts UNION would be a way to do it, but since there are 20 or even more tables, I want if there is a better way to do it...

Btw I am using SQL SERVER COMPACT in WEBMATRIX....

Answer (score 2):

Can't think of a a different way to do it except union of all query results for the tables.
The question you really need to ask yourself is, why you have so many tables with same data stored in all of them? I think that this is a bad practice and you should have one table with a field which would separate them, or even extension tables to the different type of rows.
But the bottom line - Every data which represents the same information should be stored in one table.

Comment: :Thanks for the reply.
Well i actually have data for 20 different sections of a college and thus the definition remains the same for all...

Comment: So, why not merge it into one big table and keep a foreign key of SectionID which would distinguish between the different parts?

Comment: +1 for the design advice. Having a table per department is not a good way to go about things. Creating a table for departments/sections and using that to distinguish between them in one table is a better way to do this than UNION.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use `Union` if you want to do it in a pure SQL manner.

There are some tricks using EF, inheritance and a few configuration that will give you an access to the several tables with the same columns via one collection. But I'm not an expert with this approach.

Further you could do a view combining all columns from all your tables. However SQL Server CE doesn't support views. You can do so if you'll migrate your db at least to SQL Server Express.

And finally you could generate your SQL statement in your asp.net application using stringbuilder.

Comment: Thanks :)

Gawd ! Seems a lot ! :P
Anyways thanks a lot for the reply, ill then try to work with Union itself....